# Problema con PyQt5 QTimer

Tags: python, hilos, pyqt5

Hola tengo este código y la idea es que cuando termine un cierto intervalo de tiempo, se salga del `while` y siga ejecutando hacia abajo, los requisitos es que se ocupe QTimer para esta tarea

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import time

class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tiempo = True

    def run(self):
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(self.finish)
        timer.start(5000)
        while self.tiempo:
            print(timer.isActive())
            print("we are here")

    def finish(self):
        self.tiempo = False
        print("timer timeout")



app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
thread_instance = Thread()
thread_instance.start()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Está en el lugar equivocado inicializando `QTimer`. Prueba esto:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
#import time

class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.tiempo = True
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()                                 # +++
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.finish)                      # +++
        self.timer.start(5000)                                       # +++

    def run(self):
# -       self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
# -       self.timer.timeout.connect(self.finish)
# -       self.timer.start(5000)
        while self.tiempo:
            print(f"timer is: {self.timer.isActive()}")
            print(f"we are here: tiempo = {self.tiempo}")
            self.msleep(1000)                                        # +++

    def finish(self):
        self.tiempo = False
        print(f"\ntimer timeout: tiempo = {self.tiempo}")
        self.timer.stop()                                            # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    thread_instance = Thread()
    thread_instance.finished.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)            # +++
    thread_instance.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]